# Gateway timeout when using ng build instead of ng serve

Tags: .net, angular

I am trying to deploy my small Angular app to a server. My Angular app is using a separate .NET Core - Web API.

When I run my Angular app using the following command works flawlessly... I can login into my app using the backend.

```
ng serve --host=85.214.XXX.XXX --port=4200 --disable-host-check --ssl --ssl-key /home/cert/cert.key --ssl-cert /home/cert/cert.key
```

But when I want to deploy my app for real using "ng build" and copying the files inside the dist directory to my htdocs-folder of the webserver it doesn't work.

I mean the app does start, but entering some login data into the app results in a failed POST-request due to a 504 - Gateway timeout.

Thanks for your help in advance

@Update: It cannot be a backend issue, because the login works running the app using "ng serve" but not hosting the app after building with "ng build".

@Update: It gets even weirder. It works using Firefox, but not Chrome, Edge, and all others...

Comment: Are you sure that you are referencing the right api ip address ?

Comment: Yes, ... The very same address works flawlessly in Insomnia, or other REST-Clients

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out, that the answer was the SSL configuration...

Gateway timeout can also occur (only with some browsers) when there is something wrong with the SSL config.